# Probability of a Min/Max

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation, terminology

I am studying probability for an exam and I am finding hard to understand the notion of $P(\min(X_1,X_2))$ and $P(\max(X_1,X_2))$, where $X$ is a discrete or a continuous variable.

I have found in my book that $P(\min(X_1,X_2)>t) = P(X_1>t)\cdot P(X_2>t)$ and $P(\max(X_1,X_2)\leq t) = P(X_1\leq t)\cdot P(X_2\leq t)$. Could you explain (or link) me what is the theory behind it?

Thank you very much

Comment: Could you add a little more to your post that indicates which parts of these statements you already understand and at which point you get stuck.

Comment: I have understood the mathematical/logical demonstration, I am getting stuck with its usage in easy exercises, as the one that I posted below as comment to Clement C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only true assuming $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. Assume it is the case; then, the event $E_t=\{\min(X_1,X_2) > t\}$ can be rewritten as
$$
E_t= \{X_1 > t\}\cap\{X_2 > t\}
$$
since the minimum of two quantities is greater that $t$ iff both are greater than $t$. Now,
$\mathbb{P}\left(\{X_1 > t\}\cap\{X_2 > t\}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\{X_1 > t\}\right)\cdot\mathbb{P}\left(\{X_2 > t\}\right)$ because $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

(Similarly for the $\max$ case, as $\max(X_1,X_2)\leq t\Leftrightarrow ( X_1\leq t \text{ and } X_2\leq t )$)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a last question.. Here in my book I see this example: an electronic component is made by two elements in series. Each of them has an exponential time life of 0.3 and 0.1. Which is the law of T (where T is the component time life)? My book assumes that they are independents and finds the answer using the minimum definition, as: exp(-(0.3*0.1)t). The question is, why it uses the min and not the max?

Comment: Because the component will fail as soon as at least one of its two parts fails (because the two parts are in series; the components depends on both its parts, and cannot function when any of them is broken).

Answer (score 5):

There's not really any probability or algebra involved here, it's just a question of logic.  Saying that $\min(X_1,X_2)>t$ is just the same as $X_1>t$ **and** $X_2>t$, because if the smaller one is greater than $t$ then the other one must be too.

Hence
$$P(\min(X_1,X_2)>t)=P(X_1>t\ \hbox{and}\ X_2>t)\ ,$$
and if you have suitable **independence** properties this is
$$P(X_1>t)\,P(X_2>t)\ .$$